# To get previous column data from another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table `Score_calc` where I have 3 columns to calculate score.

I need query to to get `score_id` based on below condition.

Example : Consider if I am searching value `calc_pnt <=0.6` then in table for `calc_pnt <=0.6` corresponding value `score_id` is `'4'` But I need value as `'3'` the previous one.

`Regn_code=10 and calc_pnt <=0.6` then from score_id I need value `'3'`

I tried the below

[image]

```
select max(score_id)
from (select calc_pnt,score_id,lag(score_id) over(score_id) as previous
      from Score_calc
      where calc_pnt <=0.6
     )
```

a its working I will get result as `'3'` but if I give `calc_pnt <=0.7` then I will get `'4'`

Could you please help on this

Comment: Should your outer query just be getting `max(previous)`? I'm not sure I understand either though; are you also supposed to be filtering on a single region? If not do you want one value per region, or the highest previous score from any region? (You seem to be taking 'previous' to mean 'next highest' - is that correct?)

Comment: Thanks Olovier,...Yes I am filtering on region, Basically I am comparing value with column calc_pnt and that value  has to be lesser or equal to value in calc_pnt with region and in score_id column i will take previous value....Another example would be where calc_pnt < 0.7 and regn_cd = 10; as per table score_id value is '4' but i need value '3' the previous value

Comment: Using `max(previous)` would give you 3 for <= 0.7, wouldn't it? But why are you expecting 3 for 0.6? The highest `calc_pnt` <= 0.6 is 0.4; its `score_id` is 3; the previous one is 2.

Comment: For future reference, please provide you sample data as **text**, preferably SQL statements. People cannot cut'n'paste from images, which means they need to type out everything by hand, which is tedious and time-consuming. You are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to help you: you are more likely to get a helpful response earlier if you make it easy for people to write and test code.

Comment: Unfortunately your business rules are unclear. Why is `4` wrong when the criteria is `<=0.7`. Because `0.7` is **indisputably** less than or equal to `0.7`. So either `score_id=4` is correct for `0.7` or `score_id=3` is incorrect for `0.6` and it should be `score_id=2`.

Comment: Hi.. 0.7 corresponding value is 4 but I need its previous value which is 3

Comment: @AlexPoole 0.7 it will give 3 ..yes I am expecting 3 for 0.6..I am comparing 0.6 with all column data for regn_code 10 and 0.6 is less than 0.7 so her my condition <= is true so for 0.6 also I am expecting 3

Comment: Any value I will pass in calc_pnt if it matches that condition that is <=  then previous value we need to fetch from score_id

Comment: But you are saying contradictory things. APC has explained it better than I did. If you can't explain (or don't understand) the logic you are trying to apply then we aren't going to be able to help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding what you need.  This seems to return what you want:

```
select max(score_id)
from from Score_calc
where calc_pnt < 0.6 and regn_cd = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordan..However in where condition value could be any thing..It has to search that value in calc_pnt column with condition calc_pnt<='Value' then previous value from score_id

Comment: As per my example where calc_pnt <= 0.6 and regn_cd = 10 the corresponding value in score_id is 4(As it is less than 0.7) I need previous value that is 3 from score_id